# Xamarin studio - this project type requires Xamarin.Android to be installed

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I have recently installed Win10, VS2017 Community and Xamarin Studio on my computer. My project is written in VS2017, and when I compile and run it on the device from VS2017 it all works fine, but when I open it in Xamarin studio, I get error ***"this project type requires Xamarin.Android to be installed***". I installed monodevelop, gtk sharp, build tools fool. In Android SDK Manager I installed all I needed. Also, when I press "*New solution*" in Xamarin studio, it does not offer "*Android project*". None of the answers I found doesn't works for me. All of the above mentioned worked perfectly on Win7, except that that project was written in VS2015 Community! Need help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well.  I had been developing in Visual Studio 2017 and wanted to switch to Xamarin Studio for working on layouts, since the designer and AXML intellisense is so much better.

What I discovered is that I needed to install a seperate Xamarin.Android package.  I downloaded it from this link https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads.  The universal installer didn't work for me; it only offered to install a remote iOS emulator, Xamarin Profiler, and Xamarin Workbooks, so I downloaded the separate installer and it cleared the issue up.

[image: screenshot of the Xamarin download page with Xamarin.Android 4.3 installer selected]

Comment: You made my day! :)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :)

Comment: As @M.R.Safari mentioned, the above download page no longer exists.  I solved this by downloading Visual Studio for Mac again from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

I came across this same error, and the search results brought me here. Unfortunately, the solutions above are now out of date.

I eventually solved my problem, by going to Preferences -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Android. Where it immediately showed a popup "SDK needs repair". I had to leave it to download the necessary components.

[image: SDK needs repair]

FYI, Xamarin Studio is now Visual Studio for Mac.